# Content-Disposition header is null, using JQuery $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring

I need to catch "Content-Disposition" header on https response .. about a file download, but it fails. I'm using Spring (Security) REST with HTTPS. My frontend is made with JQuery. I appreciate any help. I'm working by 2 days and .. nothing!

Important: *when i observe on browser network console .. the headers on https datagram is ok. Content-Disposition is there*. And the file (a image) already arrived from backend. it sounds strange ...

```
        $.ajax({
            url: backend+"/noauthe/filemngr/Download",
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            headers: { 'Content-Type':'image/jpeg' },
            responseType:'arraybuffer',
            timeout: 2000,
            data: JSON.stringify(fileDescriptor)
        }).success(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            var downloadBlob = document.createElement("a");
            downloadBlob.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {type: jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Content-Type")}));
            downloadBlob.download = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Content-Disposition").split("=")[1].trim();
            document.body.appendChild(downloadBlob);
            downloadBlob.click();
            document.body.removeChild(downloadBlob);
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('[ERROR]');
            console.log(jqXHR);
        });
```

[image: this pic is to help]

can anybody help me?! thanks ...

Comment: When a try catch Content-Disposition on response .. it is null. I need catch filename on this header.

Comment: Poderia traduzir a sua pergunta? Você está na versão em português do Stack Overflow.

Comment: iiiiii ehehheh, ok. Então, estou precisando acessar o 'Content-Disposition' em respostas HTTPS com o fim de ter o nome do arquivo (setado nesse cabeçalho) para download em browser. Estou usando JQuery no frontend e Spring (Security e REST) no backend. As requisições todas são feitas sobre HTTPS.

No momento que tento capturar o 'Content-Disposition' ele vem como sendo nulo. Contudo, se observar no console de depuração do browser, a aba network, os cabeçalhos estão todos lá e a imagem (o arquivo pra download) também está. Tá estranho.

Comment: o parametro timout nas opcoes da chamada ajax coloquei pra testar na última tentativa, e nada. já teste com e sem ele ..

Comment: @JulioGustavoCosta você deve [edit] a pergunta para traduzir, aí ela poderá ser reaberta.